# How can I save row numbers to a table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have added row numbers to a table (`merged`) thus:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pclass) RowNum, *
FROM merged;
```

Which returns:

```
1|1|0|58|0|0|146.5208|0|20|0|1|1|0.53043592
2|1|0|31|1|0|113.275|0|23|0|1|1|0.671198682
3|1|0|38|0|0|227.525|0|29|0|1|1|0.888825796
4|1|0|36|0|2|71|0|23|1|0|1|0.49853335
```

However, when I then check `merged`, the row numbers are no longer present (note that this produces unordered results, but nevertheless shows the point I am making):

```
SELECT * FROM merged;

2|0|24|0|0|13|0|38|1|0|0|0.505845678
3|1|61|0|0|6.2375|0|25|1|0|0|0.128146005
2|0|17|0|0|12|0|21|0|1|1|0.465261004
2|1|18|0|0|11.5|0|26|1|0|0|0.458356337
```

I suspect that the way to achieve this is to update `merged` by adding a new column and then adding the row numbers to said column, but I don't know how to go about it.

As such, my question is this: how can I save row numbers to `merged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` statement won't change the `merged` table. Updating the existing table will be a bit complicated, and I guess there is no trivial way to do that. So the easier way is to create a new table, drop the previous one and renaming the new one to be the old one.

This code should work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_merged
  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pclass) RowNum, * FROM merged); 

DROP TABLE merged;

ALTER TABLE new_merged RENAME TO merged;
```

Comment: I get the idea, but it doesn't work for me: `Error: near "SELECT": syntax error`.

Comment: Oh ya we need to remove the `VALUES`, please retry.

Comment: Not quite, but I feel like we're close: `Error: near "(": syntax error`.

Comment: Can you try removing the brackets? (https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/sql-server-insert-into-table-with-value-select-from-another-table.html) Sorry I'm not familiar with INSERT syntax statement.

Comment: This is so close, but it now results in what appears to be my entire dataset (`merged`) with no row numbers, and then it seems to have appended a further dataset of equal length which takes the form of `||||||||||||1`, `||||||||||||2`, `||||||||||||3`, `||||||||||||4` and so on.  This seems to have partially solved the issue, in that it has executed it in what appears to be two steps (create the new column, then append an equal-length dataset to the original table with only row numbers present) rather than update the existing rows' row numbers.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that you have an existing rows' row numbers. If this is the case, you can skip the `ALTER TABLE` statement, and change the insert statement to `INSERT INTO merged (YourExistingRowNumberColumn)`.

Comment: I don't already have a rows column - the column has always been created from your earlier `ALTER TABLE` statement. Each time I recreate the table to start fresh, and what seems to happen is that the new column is created and the row numbers are added, but not for the existing data. It seems to double the length of the table and only add row numbers into the `RowNumbers` column for the newly-created (blank) rows. I hope that makes things a bit clearer for you.

Comment: I see, sorry for my overlook. I guess there is no trivial way to solve that. I forgot that we must use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`, which will be more complicated. So I think an easier way to do this is just to make into a new table, using this code:
`CREATE TABLE new_merged
  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pclass) RowNum, *
FROM merged);

DROP TABLE merged;
ALTER TABLE new_merged RENAME TO merged;`

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you, Kevin. Please update your answer with your most recent comment ("There appears to be no trivial way to solve that...") and I will accept.